# Cant make a view show above another one in StackLayout-XamarinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having a problem on my XAML page, I want to show an Image above a custom view and no matter what I try it is always shown behind. I have already shown a view above this specific custom view, but in this section, I cant make it work, and I don't see the difference between this part and the one that actually works.

My code:

```
<ContentPage Title="title">
            <renderers:GradientLayout
                x:Name="page"
                ColorsList="#D81BDE,#4847FF" 
                Mode="ToBottomLeft">

                <Button 
                    BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                    HeightRequest="45"
                    WidthRequest="45"

                    Margin="0,25,25,0"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"

                    Command="{Binding button}">

                </Button>

                <CarouselView
                    x:Name="carousel" 

                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"

                    BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout>

**This is the custom view I am trying to show below**
                                <custom:PancakeView 
                                    CornerRadius="25"
                                    HasShadow="True"
                                    BackgroundColor="Pink"

                                    Margin="35,0,65,15"
                                    HeightRequest="600"
                                    WidthRequest="300"
                                    VerticalOptions="End"
                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                    Padding="15">
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Label
                                            Text="124$"
                                            FontSize="20"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            TextColor="White"

                                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                                            HorizontalOptions="End"></Label>
                                        <Label 
                                            Text="{Binding Title}"
                                            TextColor="White"
                                            FontSize="40"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"

                                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                                        <Label 
                                            Text="Este es un ejemplo de una descripcion, hace falta, por supuesto, hacer un binding con la descripcion real"
                                            TextColor="White"
                                            FontSize="20"
                                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"

                                            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            Margin="0,0,0,25"></Label>

**This is the custom view that is actually showing below**
                                        <custom:PancakeView
                                            BackgroundGradientStartColor="White"
                                            BackgroundGradientEndColor="Black"
                                            CornerRadius="25"
                                            Opacity="0.25"

                                            HeightRequest="60"
                                            WidthRequest="800"
                                            VerticalOptions="End"
                                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            Padding="3"
                                            Margin="0,0,0,35">
                                            <Frame
                                                BackgroundColor="Pink"
                                                CornerRadius="25"

                                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                Padding="0"></Frame>
                                        </custom:PancakeView>


**This is the view that it is actually showing above**
                                        <Label
                                            Text="Buy now"
                                            TextColor="White"
                                            FontSize="30"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"

                                            Margin="10,-96,10,15"
                                            VerticalOptions="End"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </custom:PancakeView>

**This is the image I am trying to show on top of the first custom view**
                                <Image
                                    Source="Burguer.png"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"

                                    VerticalOptions="End"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    Margin="0,-500,0,0"></Image>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </CarouselView>

            </renderers:GradientLayout>
        </ContentPage>
```

And that is all, if you need more info I will provide it as soon as I see your request, thank you for your time, have a nice day.

**EDIT:**
Here are two pictures, the first one is what I am trying to achieve, the second one is what is happening with this code:

[image]
[image]

Comment: it would be helpful to include a mockup of what you're trying to achieve and a screenshot of what you are actually getting

Comment: @Jaime According to your code, I can not reproduce your issue at my side, so I suggest you can provide one simple that can reproduce your issue at github.

Comment: @Jason I added two pictures to the question, is that what you asked for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to overlap layouts using [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid), and it's like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentBehind">
        //This Content will stay below
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentAbove">
        //This Content will stay on front
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

So if you want a `StackLayout` to be above another `StackLayout`, you shoul try this:

```
<Grid>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Green"><Label Text="I'm in the Background" /></StackLayout>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent"><Label Text="I'm Overlaping the other StackLayout" /></StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Or like this (it's the same thing but you define how you want your rows height to act):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Green"><Label Text="I'm in the Background" /></StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent"><Label Text="I'm Overlaping the other StackLayout" /></StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That works, any idea why it does not work with a stacklayout?

Comment: @JaimeSantos StackLayouts are meant to "Stack" on top of eachother, while Grids arrange views into rows and columns (that's why they overlapp, bot Grids inside the Grid are on the Row 0 and Collumn 0), here is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/choose-layout it's very well documented and it can help you with this type of questions

Comment: I have added an extra way for overlapping the StackLayouts, and if it worked, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer as it helps alot and it helps others finding the correct anwser right of the back

Comment: I also edited the previous code, since i think i have confused you with the Grids wrapping the StackLayout